# Retrieve Data in Listview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to retrieve multiple data in from firebase database into Listview Android.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QerBE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have not shown what you attempted, below is a sample code which may work for you. First, create o model for your Database:

```
public class Container {

    public HashMap<String, Model> models;
    public class Model {
        public int id;
        public String name;
    }
}
```

And use it to retrieve data from Firebase:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("your path").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Container yourData = dataSnapshot.getValue(Container.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your DatabaseReference with a ChildEventListener, and override the on ChildAdded method.

this is an example to help you start with:

```
ChildEventListener mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {

           @Override
           public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String s) {

//Get the data that you want from the snapShot and add it to your ListView's adapter  here. Use the Adapter's Add() method. 

  } 

           @Override
           public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

           }
       };
    DatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
```

[You can get More Help Here.(Firebase Documentation)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)